# Linking tkinter entries to each others input

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make 2 entries display strings based on each others input. E.g if I type 10 in the entry1 entry2 displays 10*2, same for entry2 but entry1 must display 10/2.
I tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("700x350")
varEntry1=StringVar()
varEntry2=StringVar()

varEntry1.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode, varEntry1=varEntry1: callback(varEntry1))
varEntry2.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode, varEntry2=varEntry2: callback2(varEntry2))



entry1 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=varEntry1)
entry2 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=varEntry2)


def callback(varEntry1):
  
    print (varEntry1.get())
    entry2.delete(0,END)
    entry2.insert(0,float(varEntry1.get())*2)

def callback2(varEntry2):
  
    print (varEntry2.get())
    entry1.delete(0,END)
    entry1.insert(0,float(varEntry2.get())/2)



entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()
```

But it seems like entry tracings mess with each other and input gets deleted after I type 2nd symbol.
Then i tried to create function that will disable trace for entry2 on click on entry1 but it didn't work.
Is there more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("700x350")
varEntry1=StringVar()
varEntry2=StringVar()

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=varEntry1)
entry2 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=varEntry2)

def callback(event): ### EDITED LINE

    print(varEntry1.get())
    entry2.delete(0,END)
    entry2.insert(0,float(varEntry1.get())*2)

def callback2(event): ### EDITED LINE

    print(varEntry2.get())
    entry1.delete(0,END)
    entry1.insert(0,float(varEntry2.get())/2)

entry1.bind("<Return>", callback) ### ADDED LINE
entry2.bind("<Return>", callback2) ### ADDED LINE

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This uses the `bind()` function of the entries, so that whenever the user hits enter after typing in the entry, it performs the calculations. This way, you can type a number of any size before it calculates.

If you want to do it while still using the `trace()` function, you can have it perform the calculations when the user hits a certain key, such as `:`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("700x350")
varEntry1=StringVar()
varEntry2=StringVar()

varEntry1.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode, varEntry1=varEntry1: callback(varEntry1))
varEntry2.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode, varEntry2=varEntry2: callback2(varEntry2))

entry1 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=varEntry1)
entry2 = ttk.Entry(root,textvariable=varEntry2)

def callback(varEntry1):
  
    if ":" in varEntry1.get():
        entry2.delete(0,END)
        entry2.insert(0,float(varEntry1.get().replace(":", ""))*2)

def callback2(varEntry2):
  
    if ":" in varEntry2.get():
        entry1.delete(0,END)
        entry1.insert(0,float(varEntry2.get().replace(":", ""))/2)

entry1.pack()
entry2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You can use any character in place of `:`, (I don't recommend using `.`, however :-)).

Comment: That's a good solution. But I wonder if  there is any way to perform the calculations using callback from textvariable trace?

Comment: @YaroslavLebedyansky: Well, that would require you to use a different key press instead of `"<Return>"`. `StringVar` cannot detect key presses, and since the your input widgets are `Entry`, pressing enter won't change the text like it would in a `Text`. There are two alternatives here: using another symbol to trigger the calculations (for example, `:`), or using `Text` instead of `Entry`. Using the latter method, you could check if there was a newline in `StringVar.get()`, and trigger the calculations that way. If you want me to change my answer to either of these solutions, let me know.

Comment: I tried to do it myself but did not succeed. Can you pleae change the answer so that StringVar.get() triggers the calculations. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @YaroslavLebedyansky: I updated the answer. See what you think. It ended up being impossible to use the `Text` method I mentioned in my previous comment, because `Text` doesn't have a `textvariable` option.